# Set up a GRE tunnel with Cisco PIX-506 v6.3

Tags: vpn, cisco, cisco-pix, gre

I'm trying to establish one half of a GRE tunnel, the other being configured by my service provider.  I have a Cisco PIX-506-E running Firewall version 6.3(5).

Provider Router Public IP: 8.8.8.8
My PIX Public IP: 7.7.7.7

Provider Tunnel Address: 192.168.99.1/30
My Tunnel Address: 192.168.99.2/30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but a PIX/ASA device is not capable of being an endpoint for GRE tunneling.  You'll need a router device instead.

Answer (score 2):

Cisco ASA devices don't support being GRE tunnel endpoints. You need to use a Cisco router if you want a Cisco device terminating that tunnel.

Answer (score -3):

Here is a guide for [Setting up a GRE Tunnel on a Cisco router](https://www.incapsula.com/blog/setting-up-a-gre-tunnel-on-a-cisco-router.html) but as the poster above said, you need a router, not an ASA device.

Comment: Link-only answers are strongly discouraged. Please provide content **here** and then link elsewhere for more details.