# Setting up a GRE tunnel on a Cisco ASA 5505

Tags: vpn, cisco-asa, gre

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set up a GRE tunnel with Cisco PIX-506 v6.3](https://serverfault.com/questions/366927/set-up-a-gre-tunnel-with-cisco-pix-506-v6-3)

I'm trying to establish one half of a GRE tunnel, the other being configured by my service provider. I have a Cisco ASA 5505 running ASA version 8.2(2), ASDM version 6.2(5)

Provider Router Public IP: 8.8.8.8 My PIX Public IP: 7.7.7.7

Provider Tunnel Address: 192.168.99.1/30 My Tunnel Address: 192.168.99.2/30

I'm not too familiar with Cisco ASA, but I have some experience with routing and IOS.  I'm basically looking for a mini howto. Bounty points for well written step by step instructions on how to set up a GRE tunnel with the ASA 5505.